# Problem creating a node with custom PHP code

Tags: nodes

I wrote the following custom PHP code to create a node

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

global $user;
$title1=$node->title;
$node = new stdClass;
$node->type = 'Campaign_PlayerList';
$node->title = $title1;
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->language='und';
$node->field_cmp_playerid['und'][0]['value']=$user->uid;
$node->field_cmp_userscore['und'][0]['value']=1;
$node->field_cmp_usersupport['und'][0]['value']=1;
node_object_prepare($node);
node_save($node);
?>
```

The values for `field_cmp_playerid` and `field_cmp_attend_time` are not saved.

```
$node->field_cmp_playerid['und'][0]['value']=$user->uid;
```

doesnt work and `field_cmp_attend_time` is the same too.

What could the problem be?

Here is a screenshot of the field management form for the Campaign Playerlist content type:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks from your image like `field_cmp_playerid` is a user reference field, which means the column name won't be `value`, it will be `uid`. Try this code:

```
$node->field_cmp_playerid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uid'] = $user->uid;
```

The `field_cmp_attend_time` field probably isn't getting saved because it's missing from your code. It's just a date field so the column name will be `value`. If the date field you're using is a UNIX timestamp type, for example, the code would look like this:

```
$node-> field_cmp_playerid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = REQUEST_TIME;
```

Just in case you want to update your `field_cmp_id` as well, it's a node reference so the column name becomes `nid`:

```
$node->field_cmp_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = $nid;
```

Comment: Thank you Clive! And Thx for helping me revise my question.